# How to check if point moved or is on a different line in a buffer since the last user command?

Tags: hooks, commands, point, line-numbers

I would like to make a snippet of code that only executes if the point is on a different line in a particular buffer since the last user command. The only way I could think to do it was using the post-command-hook:

```
(setq my-prev-line 0)

(defun my-install-move-hook (buf)
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-move-hook nil t)))

(defun my-move-hook ()
  (when (and my-prev-line (= my-prev-line (line-number-at-pos)))
    (message "The point moved from line number %d to %d" my-prev-line (line-number-at-pos))
    (setq my-prev-line (line-number-at-pos))))
```

That seems like overkill, since `post-command-hook` triggers after **every** command, not just user-invoked commands. Would it be better if the line number was stored during `pre-command-hook`?

Comment: There is only rarely any distinction between "commands" and "user-invoked commands", so that comment sounds a little odd.  Which are the 'not-user-invoked' commands you are wishing to avoid?

Comment: A user-invoked command is a command that is directly invoked by the user typing a keyboard shortcut for the command or running ```M-x <name of command>```. For example, suppose that I have commands ```foo``` and  ```baz```, and ```baz``` calls ```foo``` 3 times. If the user invokes either ```foo``` or ```baz``` directly, there has been only one user-invoked command, but the ```post-command-hook``` would be called either once or four times (assuming that ```foo``` did something trivial).

Comment: For some background, I want to create a special buffer that runs a command ```foo``` that is a function of line-number at point. At first, I rebound ```<up>```, ```<down>```, ```C-p```, and ```C-n``` to functions that run ```(foo (line-number-at-pos))``` after the normal movement command, but then ```foo``` isn't run for all other movement commands, like ```scroll-down-command``` or ```isearch-forward```. I tried using a buffer-local ```post-command-hook``` like above, but that gets caught in infinite loops if the code in  ```post-command-hook``` also moves the point in the buffer.

Comment: If `bar` calls `(foo ...)` that's not a separate command.  A typical command might cause vast numbers of function calls, but it's still just one time around the command loop, and `post-command-hook` runs at the end of the command loop.  Calling a function is not the same thing as invoking a command (even when the function being called could itself be invoked as a command).

Comment: Calculating line numbers is expensive. Why don't you place a marker at the beginning of the line in the pre-command hook and check if it's on the same line as the point in the post-command hook?

Comment: How do we check if the point is on the same line as a marker? Is it something like  ```(and (marker-position m1) (= (line-beginning-position) (marker-position m1)))```? Why is ```(line-beginning-position)``` more efficient than ```(line-number-at-pos)```?

Comment: @shankar2k, because finding the position of the start of the line is fast (at worst, Emacs steps one character at a time until the beginning of the line). Calculating the liner number requires Emacs to search through the entire text from the beginning to the point.

Answer (score 2):

You say: *"post-command-hook triggers after every command, not just user-invoked commands."*  And in comments you say that by "user-invoked" you really mean invoked *interactively*.

It's not true that `post-command-hook` triggers each time a function that is a command is invoked.  It's triggered for such a function only when it is invoked interactively:

```lisp
(defun foo () (interactive) (message "THIS: %s, FOO" this-command) (bar))
(defun bar () (interactive) (message "THIS: %s, BAR" this-command))
(defun toto () 
  (message "TOTO, THIS: %s" this-command)
  (when (equal this-command 'foo)
    (message "TOTO, FOO was invoked")))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'toto)
```

This is what `*Messages*` shows, when you evaluate `(foo)`, that is, you do *not* invoke `foo` interactively (i.e., as a command):

```lisp
THIS: eval-last-sexp, FOO
THIS: eval-last-sexp, BAR
"THIS: eval-last-sexp, BAR"
TOTO, THIS: eval-last-sexp
```

And this is what `*Messages*` shows when you do `M-x foo`, that is, you invoke `foo` interactively (i.e., as a command):

```lisp
TOTO, THIS: execute-extended-command
TOTO, THIS: self-insert-command [3 times]
THIS: foo, FOO
THIS: foo, BAR
TOTO, THIS: foo
TOTO, FOO was invoked
```

You can put conditional code in your hook function, to do whatever you want when `foo` is invoked *as a command*. That's what the test `(equal this-command 'foo)` does above. You can see that `toto` prints `TOTO, FOO was invoked` only when `foo` is invoked as a command (e.g. `M-x`).

---

Alternatively, depending on what you really want, use function `called-interactively`, to test whether `foo` has been invoked *as a command*.